# Looking for the English term for rewriting an equation to express a variable

Tags: terminology

If I rewrite an equation

$$\sqrt{a} + b = 10$$

to

$$a = 100 - 20b + b^2,$$

how would I call that transformation to explicitly express $a$?

Comment: Is "solving for $a$ and expanding the square using the binomial theorem" precise enough for your needs?

Comment: I think "solving for a" is what I was looking for. Can you make that an answer? :)

Comment: One could also say you're *isolating* $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposting my comment on the OP's request:

> Is *"solving for $a$ and expanding the square using the binomial formula"* precise enough for your needs?

Comment: *Just* solving for $a$, without any other transformation, would be $a = (10 - b)^2$.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

What about 'isolating'? Or 'extricating'?

Comment: 'isolating' was already suggested in the comments.